# How to say that someone is humble (in a positive way)?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

I could not find a direct translation for the word *humble* in German.

The meaning I am searching for is a positive one, like when you say:

> He is a humble man.

He does not show off; he is not arrogant. I don’t want to say that he is low, small nor has no self esteem or confidence .

I once tried to say *de­mü­tig*, but I got a negative reaction from the Germans who heard me.

Comment: Actually I would also have proposed *demütig*, but the word has a somewhat dated touch, and is often used in religious context. If I remember correctly, one the new chairs of the German green party, Mr Habeck, used it after his election last week, so I would consider it more one the side good choice than in *where did you find that word*.

Comment: https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/humble - bescheiden, ärmlich, demütig, gering, niedrig. In your context *bescheiden* is the word you are looking for.

Comment: what about aufrecht? As applied to personality, not the stature.

Comment: IMHO - in my humble opinion. Meiner bescheidenen Meinung nach.

Comment: From google translator, "humble man" is translated with "einfacher Mann", which is perfectly fine with a positive meaning

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: If someone told me "A ist ein einfacher Mann.", I'd understand that to mean that A is not exactly among the intellectual elite. Quite some context is required to understand *einfach* as *humble*.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Looks like it is a case of preference then. I do understand "einfach" as "humble" in that sentence

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The concept of being humble in the positive sense is best reflected in the German virtue of

> [Bescheidenheit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bescheidenheit), bescheiden sein

If you can read the German Wikipedia you will find a lot of German phrases that have their analogy in the English *being humble* but still there are many phrases with a negative connotation where *Bescheidenheit* is used in the meaning of *poor*.

It is mainly the context that decides about the connotation of *bescheiden sein*.

Comment: Hmm. Everyone seems to claim *humble* in English cannot mean *poor* - But it does. So *bescheiden* is pretty correct.

Comment: @tofro - I wouldn't say it means "poor" exactly (but it is close).  For instance, a common phrase is "He came from humble beginnings".  This fits [one of the definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/humble) "ranking low in a hierarchy or scale ."

Comment: @BruceWayne: In that particular case, I'd rather interpret *humble* as a euphemism. As in: They had little money, nothing to eat, no luxury? Oh, no, no! They didn't *want* much, they didn't *ask* for more. They were humble. I think the interpretation as "ranking low in a hierarchy of scale" is mostly found with things, e.g. "Der Film war bescheiden." = "The film was poor/pretty bad." Maybe the boundary to a euphemism is blurry, and it should also be noted that *bescheiden* can be used to "mask" the vulgar word *beschissen*.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use the adjective **bescheiden** because of its connotation to poverty and possible insults, you have to use a negative phrase:

> Er prahlt nicht (mit …).
>
> Er gibt nicht (mit …) an.

*He doesn't boast (about …).*

Answer (score 5):

In this context I suggest

> bescheiden

as translation of "humble". So your sentence reads "Er ist ein bescheidener Mann." In this context "bescheiden" is a positive word and describes what you mentioned.

But note, that "bescheiden" can have a negative meaning. As mentioned in the comments, for example "Er lebt bescheiden." can mean "He's living poor".

Comment: +1, but *bescheiden* in many situations also has a negative connotation, of sugarcoating poverty or even insulting someone as poor, or poor in mind.

Comment: You can get rid of the negative context by phrasing. Compare: *"Er lebt bescheiden."* - *"Er ist bescheiden."* - *"Er ist eine bescheidene Persönlichkeit"*. First one means that he is probably poor, the second one is ambiguous, the third one says that he is a humble personality. If you want to avoid the negative phrase from @Janka's answer, this is the only way that comes to mind.

Comment: But don't accidentally say *Er **hat** eine bescheidene Persönlichkeit.*

Comment: @Janka Correct, but doesn't hurt, as *humble* has the same possible connotations in English.

Answer (score 3):

*unprätentiös* might be the one you're looking for if you want to describe a person's character and don't want the possible "poor" notation *bescheiden* has.
This word is, however, not really commonly used.

In case you are happy with some wider distance from the original, *bodenständig* (which literally translates to "down-to-earth", another meaning of *humble*) could be an acceptable translation.